# Sharepoint list and a word doc

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, ms-office

Hi
I have a word templateis used as a content type. I want the document to be used as read and write data to a sharepoint list. 
I also want this document to track changes. Is this possible? 
Say user1 edits the doc, saves it
User2 makes some changes. saves it.

Now since i am actually "databinding" to a list, can i track changes?

And eventually i want to push this data to a record center

Comment: Can you go into more detail about what you mean by, `I want the document to be used as read and write data to a sharepoint list.`?

Answer (score 1):

You can track changes using the built in versioning tools for SharePoint.  Give this link a read:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262378.aspx

Comment: Hmm ok. So here is the requirment. So the data i enter in the document should be saved to a list and also a DB. The document template has few content controls.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to achieve, but if you did, let me know how. I tried something similar and it's easier in InfoPath, but I have no use for it at work. As for versioning control - that is within SP out of the box; the answer above should do it.